# Open Source AI/Robotics Simulation Project

Tags: windows, simulation, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am looking for an open source simulator for robotics where the simulation has a physics engine and you are able to build not only the robot but code it's software with capabilities as real to life as possible.

I thought it would be an amazing way to test out machine learning code and set up scenarios that mimic real life situations with as many factors as possible included to see how the robots A.I. software handles it.

I understand this would be an advanced program but I was wondering if anyone is aware of any open source projects that are working on something like this.

I have a powerful workstation so it would be a cheap way to get into robotics with out having to actually pay to build one myself.

I would really appreciate any help that anyone could offer to help me.
thank you!